# Tab key sometimes switches between Object/Edit mode, but sometimes between Weight Paint/Edit

Tags: interface

Normally, when I hit Tab while in Edit mode, I switch to Object mode, and vice versa.

However, at seemingly-random times, I will hit Tab in Edit mode and instead switch to Weight Paint. Hitting Tab again does not return me to Edit mode.

I cannot figure out any reason for this. Is there something I don't know about Blender's hotkey system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it works. If you go into a paint mode via a mouse click and then hit tab it will switch between edit and paint mode. Now if you go and click on the object mode and then hit tab it will switch between object and edit mode.

That is to say the last mode you select via a mouse click becomes the sticky mode that the "tab" key will switch to.

The beauty of this is so that when you need to do different sets of operations you could.

1. Vertex paint > edit
2. Object mode > edit
3. Sculpt mode > edit
4. etc ... you get the point I hope.

Comment: Weird... I can't remember ever manually going into Paint mode. Must have misclicked something.

Comment: A shortcut key to the specific mode could also cause this , for example "v" key is the default shortcut for "vertex paint mode" so you might have accidentally press on it while working in blender.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make change edit mode with object mode? If I have to weight paint many different parts it's kinda annoying to change the mode manually..